# i want to inplement multiple words in left condition

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

Ihave written a if condition using left condition, that if the cell first 3 characters are "CAK" then copy the cell and paste it to another sheet. it worked successfully, but now i want to search for 5, 6 words to search like "CAK", "BDD, "GHH", "BAK", "GHH", Can any one tell me how to keep multiple words,

I want VBA code like if the cell first 3 characters are "CAK" or "BDD" or "GHH" or "BAK" or "GHH" then copy and paste.

```
Sub NOTES()

For C = 27 To 33

    A = Worksheets("EDAT").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For I = 12 To A

    Worksheets("EDAT").Activate
    Worksheets("EDAT").Cells(I, C).Activate

     If (Left(ActiveCell, 3) = "CAK") Then
        Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(I, C).COPY
        Worksheets("sheet2").Activate
        b = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(I, 10).COPY
        Worksheets("sheet2").Activate
        Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 8).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(I, 11).COPY
        Worksheets("sheet2").Activate
        Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 9).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If

    Next

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Where you are new, just a friendly reminder to please be sure to select the answer you choose.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change this:

```
If (Left(ActiveCell, 3) = "CAK") Then
```

to this:

```
If ((Left(ActiveCell, 3) = "CAK") or Left(ActiveCell, 3) = "BDD") or Left(ActiveCell, 3) = "GHH") or Left(ActiveCell, 3) = "BAK")) then
```

Comment: I'm very glad to hear that! :) You are very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MATCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match) method to match value against array.

```
.Match (Arg1, Arg2, Arg3)
Arg1    Required    Variant Lookup_value.
Arg2    Required    Variant Lookup_array.
Arg3    Optional    Variant Match_type: the number -1, 0, or 1.
```

Or you can use following function:

```
Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Long
  Dim i As Long
  ' default return value if value not found in array
  IsInArray = -1

  For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If StrComp(stringToBeFound, arr(i), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
      IsInArray = i
      Exit For
    End If
  Next i
End Function
```

And then call the above:

```
array= Split("CAK,BDD,GHH,BAK,GHH", ",")
IsInArray(CellValue, array)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the same thing each time the three characters match, then try the following:

```
If (Left(ActiveCell, 3) = "CAK" Or Left(ActiveCell, 3) = "BDD" Or Left(ActiveCell, 3) = "GHH" Or Left(ActiveCell, 3) = "BAK" Or Left(ActiveCell, 3) = "GHH") Then
```

This can be cleaned up a bit by using a String Array and looping over it:

```
Dim matchingLetters As Variant
matchingLetters = Array("CAK", "BDD", "GHH", "BAK", "GHH")

For Each str In matchingLetters
    If (Left(ActiveCell, 3) = str) Then
        Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(I, C).COPY
        Worksheets("sheet2").Activate
        b = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(I, 10).COPY
        Worksheets("sheet2").Activate
        Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 8).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(I, 11).COPY
        Worksheets("sheet2").Activate
        Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 9).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
Next
```